# ThymeLeaf: Setting existing attributes with th:{attribute}

Tags: java, thymeleaf

In the [ThymeLeaf Tutorial](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#setting-value-to-specific-attributes) for "Setting value for specific attributes", they both define the `href` attribute and set it using `th:href`.

#### Example Snippet Taken from Text

```
<li><a href="product/list.html" th:href="@{/product/list}">Product List</a></li>
```

Is there a reason to include the `href` tag since it will be set anyways? Are they setting these values in case if someone wants a static view of a page, i.e no renderer?

Comment: Yes, that's the reason for including the static value.

Answer (score 1):

if you question is how to add attr with href :

```html
<li>
  <a href="product/list.html" th:href="@{product/list(attrName=${attrValue})}"> 
      Product List 
  </a>
</li>
```

if you question is how to redirect to static page :

```html
// *** link to another page ***
<a th:href="@{staticPage}"> static page</a>
```

```html
// *** Spring boot Controller ***
@RequestMapping(value="/staticPage", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String staticPage(Model model) {
   return "staticPage";
}
```